# Adding Notification Center observer to NSObject class

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode9

Tring to add notification observer to a custom class(base class is NSObject).

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.methodOfReceivedNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("RegistrationCAll"), object: nil)
 }
```

Not able to receive the event.is it possible to add observer to nsobject custom class?

Comment: How you are calling that ? and how you are assigning and initialise your class ?

Comment: "it possible to add observer to nsobject custom class?" Yes it should be, where is the issue so far?

Comment: let registrationObj                    = RegistrationInterFace()
     registrationObj.delegate     = self
     registrationObj.container    = self
     registrationObj.configurePayment()

Comment: Not able to receive notification @ahmad F